# Prove that any completely regular semigroup $S$ satisfies the identities $ab=a(ba)^0b=a(b^0a^0)^0b$, $a,b\in{}S$

Tags: proof-writing, semigroups

Consider any completely regular semigroup $S$. I would like to prove, that
any $a,b\in{S}$ satisfies the identities $ab=a(ba)^0b=a(b^0a^0)^0b$, $a,b\in{}S$.

So far, I was able to prove only the first equation and I would appreciate any
help with the second one. I will show you how I proved the first one:

First, consider the "inverse product formula" for completely regular semigroups, which states
$$(ab)^{-1}=(ab)^0b^{-1}(ba)^0a^{-1}(ab)^0$$
By using this, we can get that
\begin{align}ab&=ab(ab)^0=ab(ab)^{-1}ab=ab(ab)^0b^{-1}(ba)^0a^{-1}(ab)^0ab=\\&=
abb^{-1}(ba)^0a^{-1}ab=ab^0(ba)^0a^0b=a(ba)^0b
\end{align}

which proves the first identity. (In the last step, I used the rule $a^0(ab)^k=(ab)^k=(ab)^kb^0,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$.)
But I am struggeling with the second one, so I would appreciate any help :-)

Comment: What is the meaning of $a^0$ ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: $a^0$ is the identity of $H_a$ where $H_a$ is the class of Rees $\mathcal{H}$ equivalence containing $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, we can use the same "strategy" as with the first identity, the key is just being able to cleverly rewrite the product $ab$. Here is how
$$ab=a(a^0b^0)b=a(a^0b^0)^0b=a(a^0b^0)(a^0b^0)^{-1}(a^0b^0)b$$

Now we can again use the "inverse product formula" for semigroups for $(a^0b^0)^{-1}$
and some similar steps as in the proof of the first identity. Eventually, we get that
$$ab=a(b^0a^0)^0b$$